# dompdf working fine with non-latin languages but for Arabic, the words are broken not proper

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I am using the dompdf library with CodeIgniter PHP and in my application, I have to convert the HTML to PDF through DOMPDF but I am facing issue while the HTML content contains the Arabic text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you have tried and maybe some code.

Comment: I am working with CodeIgniter PHP. So, below is the code which I am using in Controller to create the PDF from HTML content.

Comment: $message = mb_convert_encoding($message, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
 
 $this->dompdf->load_html(utf8_decode($message), 'UTF-8');

 $this->dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);

 $this->dompdf->setPaper('A3', 'portrait');

 $this->dompdf->render();

 $filename = 'abc'.time().'.pdf';

 $output = $this->dompdf->output();

NOTE: $message contains the HTML content.

Comment: And this is my PHP code which I am using in my view file to define the HTML content for the $message.

Comment: $message = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

</head>
<body style="">

    <table width="100%" border="0"   style="font-size: 11px;">
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"  style="padding: 10px;""><p style="font-family: firefly, dejavu sans mono,sans-serif;letter-spacing: 0px;"><strong>Dear <span class="lw">'. utf8_decode($fname) .'</span>'.' '.'<span class="lw">'. utf8_decode($name) . '</span>,</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>';

Comment: In this content, $fname and $lname contains the Arabic text. Which is not properly displaying while generating the PDF.

Comment: Dompdf (up to 0.8.0, the current release as of this comment) does not have good support for Arabic and some other scripts. You might want to read and follow [issue #712](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/712).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have gone through with the issue #712 and followed the steps. But, unfortunately, I got stuck in a phase where it tells me to change "text_renderer.cls.php file" in the include folder. The problem is I am not having the include folder in my dompdf library. So do you have any solution for it so pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included meta tag ?

Please write this line at top of your view file if not there.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Comment: Yes, I have included this meta tag in my HTML Head section,  Thanks for quick response.